# Finding unknown constants

Tags: limits

As $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\tan 2x - 2\sin ax}{x-x\cos 2x} = b$ where $a$ and $b$ are real constants. Then what is the value of $a$ and $b.$ Can someone help me with idea on how to approach this problem.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have any ideas

Comment: Can you expand the numerator and denominator in Taylor series?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:

If $a\ne 1$, we have $\tan 2x-2\sin ax\sim_0 2(1-a)x$, whereas $1-\cos 2x\sim_0 2x^2$, so
$$\frac{\tan 2x-2\sin ax}{x(1-\cos 2x)}\sim_0\frac{1-a}{x^2}\to \pm\infty.$$
Therefore, if the quotient has a (finite) limit, necessarily $a=1$. Proceed using Taylor's formula at least up to order $3$ to determine the value of this limit.